# Why is the method list obtained by the reflection call inconsistent with android SDK

Tags: android, reflection

The system version of my phone is Android 13, and the API version is 32. I used reflection to get the method list of AccessibilityManager.java, but the list is inconsistent with SDK. For example, there is no public method getClient in the method list of reflection calls.

```
        try {
            Class clazz= Class.forName("android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager");
            Method[] methods = clazz.getMethods();
            for(Method method:methods){
                Log.e(TAG,method.getName());
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[image]

[image]

I tried to change the API version to 33 34, the result is the same. I'm a bit confused why they don't match

Answer (score 0):

There is no getClient method on that class.  See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager

Comment: I see getClient here https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityManager.java;l=96?q=AccessibilityManager&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject

Comment: @bay0max Notice the hide annotation above it? That hides it from various tools.  That function is not part of the interface of the class, and can be changed at any time without warning.  There's no promise your version of Android even has it-  it may not be in the version that's compiled on your phone.

Comment: Besides，I type “import android.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManager;” on Android Studio and click goto Declaration or Usages. I can see method getClient but I can't access this method in my project

Comment: That means absolutely nothing.  It means its in the sources published with the SDK.  It doesn't mean its part of the actual compiled version of code on your phone or emulator.  Neither runs pure AOSP.  In either case, if you find a function like that it should not be used, as it isn't stable.

Comment: I see! I don't know enough about hide annotation, thank you for your explanation